# HTML Canvas - Drag and resize uploaded image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am doing a drawing app for a college project and currently im able to upload images into the canvas and i want to make those images resizable/draggable.
I've seen this great [example](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LAS8L/) and tried to apply it in my project for hours but with no success.

Is it possible to apply it to an uploaded image instead of preloaded image like in that example?

My javascript code to upload image and a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pedrovil/ebx93xvg/). Thanks in advance.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
function readImage() {
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
           var img = new Image();
           img.onload = function() {
             ctx.drawImage(img, true, true);
           };
           img.src = e.target.result;
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}
el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

Comment: You can check my below answer

Comment: It's better if you use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have provided a nice example, I just included those *methods* and *variables* in your code and added `jquery` then declared the `var img = new Image();` variable outside of the `readImage` function.

That's it I did and it worked as you expected.

Here you go,

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;


var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
var resizerRadius = 8;
var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius;
var draggingResizer = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
var imageX = 50;
var imageY = 50;
var imageWidth, imageHeight, imageRight, imageBottom;
var draggingImage = false;
var startX;
var startY;

function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

var img = new Image();

function readImage() {
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
           img = new Image();
           img.onload = function() {
             imageWidth = img.width;
             imageHeight = img.height;
             imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
             imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
             draw(true, false);
           };
           img.src = e.target.result;
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}

el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);


function draw(withAnchors, withBorders) {

    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw the image
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    // optionally draw the draggable anchors
    if (withAnchors) {
        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageY);
        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageY);
        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageBottom);
        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageBottom);
    }

    // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
    if (withBorders) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(imageX, imageY);
        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageY);
        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageBottom);
        ctx.lineTo(imageX, imageBottom);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}

function drawDragAnchor(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, resizerRadius, 0, pi2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function anchorHitTest(x, y) {

    var dx, dy;

    // top-left
    dx = x - imageX;
    dy = y - imageY;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (0);
    }
    // top-right
    dx = x - imageRight;
    dy = y - imageY;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (1);
    }
    // bottom-right
    dx = x - imageRight;
    dy = y - imageBottom;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (2);
    }
    // bottom-left
    dx = x - imageX;
    dy = y - imageBottom;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
        return (3);
    }
    return (-1);

}


function hitImage(x, y) {
    return (x > imageX && x < imageX + imageWidth && y > imageY && y < imageY + imageHeight);
}


function handleMouseDown(e) {
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    draggingResizer = anchorHitTest(startX, startY);
    draggingImage = draggingResizer < 0 && hitImage(startX, startY);
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    draggingResizer = -1;
    draggingImage = false;
    draw(true, false);
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {

    if (draggingResizer > -1) {

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        // resize the image
        switch (draggingResizer) {
            case 0:
                //top-left
                imageX = mouseX;
                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                imageY = mouseY;
                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                break;
            case 1:
                //top-right
                imageY = mouseY;
                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                break;
            case 2:
                //bottom-right
                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                break;
            case 3:
                //bottom-left
                imageX = mouseX;
                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                break;
        }

        if(imageWidth<25){imageWidth=25;}
        if(imageHeight<25){imageHeight=25;}

        // set the image right and bottom
        imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
        imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight;

        // redraw the image with resizing anchors
        draw(true, true);

    } else if (draggingImage) {

        imageClick = false;

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
        var dx = mouseX - startX;
        var dy = mouseY - startY;
        imageX += dx;
        imageY += dy;
        imageRight += dx;
        imageBottom += dy;
        // reset the startXY for next time
        startX = mouseX;
        startY = mouseY;

        // redraw the image with border
        draw(false, true);

    }
}


$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

```css
#canvas {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' id="fileUpload" />
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```